# Removing file extention from url in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am trying to remove the extentions from my website, for example:

http://www.domain.com/index.php becomes http://www.domain.com/index

http://www.domain.com/books-today.php becomes http://www.domain.com/books-today etc. for all the php files. This is how my .htaccess loks like so far:

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^advice/([a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /advice.php?advice=$1&id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^book/([a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /book.php?book=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

I've been trying but with no results, since I read somewhere that the resolution given will not work when the php file has "-" in it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using .htaccess to remove PHP file extension from URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13540353/using-htaccess-to-remove-php-file-extension-from-url)

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

This worked out well for me.